# Set all elements to the width of the widest in set

Tags: jquery

I have a few elements with different width. I need to loop though each, find the width of the widest and set all to that width.

```
<div id="mySet">
    <span>some content</span>
    <span>more content</span>
    <span>here content</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var widest = 0;

$("#mySet span").each(function(){
   var this = $(this),
       wdth = this.width();

   if(wdth > widest ){
       widest = wdth;

       $("#mySet span").each(function(){
           $(this).width(widest);
       });
   }

});
```

I think I can get the max width but do I loop every time to assign the width to each element. Seems like too many loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatives to looping to get the widest:

```
// Using modern JavaScript:
const widest = Math.max(...$("#mySet span").map((i, span) => $(span).width()));

// Using older JavaScript:
var widest = Math.max.apply(
  null,
  $("#mySet span").map(function() {
    return $(this).width();
  })
);
```

And then `$("#mySet span").width(widest);` to set the widths of all spans in one go.

Comment: What does ellipsis do?

Comment: In this case, it takes each width in the array returned by map, and passes each as separate arguments to the max function

Answer (score 2):

To set width to all the `span`, you just need to

```
$("#mySet span").width(widest);
```

and this will set width to all. So put it outside the loop and at the end.